# Universal Analytics not working correctly

Tags: events, google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics, event-tracking

I'm updating the old analytics to Universal Analytics, but i'm having problems.

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'website.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

That's is the new code i pasted in my head file. But when i use de Analytics debugger (for Chrome) and i run a command like:

```
ga("send", "event", "navigation", "Click", "Home");
```

I get a error like this (in debugger):

```
Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
```

I'm getting realtime data in analytics, so i know that the code is working for simple tracking. Event tracking is the problem.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2):

## Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined

This mean that your tracker is not initialized correctly or it is not initialized and you are trying to send data on them.

## Problem

Problem should be  `ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'website.com');` where you set website.com
The question is: Are your events fired from same domain? This should be equal to `document.location.hostname`.

## Testing

For testing, try it with auto parameter as cookieDomain. If this works, focus your energy into cookieDomain area.

## Other possibilities

Some people reach this issue in different was, try to learn from them:

- [Existing Google Analytics events and Google Tag Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28765806/existing-google-analytics-events-and-google-tag-manager)
- [Google Universal Analytics - Command ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697966/google-universal-analytics-command-ignored)

## Documentation

- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#configuring_cookie_field_settings
- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#cookieDomain